Show $\langle e_n|p_z|e_m\rangle=a\langle e_n|z|e_m\rangle$ for some energy eigenbasis $\{ |e_i\rangle \}$
As the problem says, let $\{ |e_i\rangle\}$ be a basis of the Hamiltonian $$\mathcal{H}=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(z).$$ I want to show that $$\langle e_n|p_z|e_m\rangle=a\langle e_n|z|e_m\rangle,$$ where $a\propto E_n-E_m$ is a proportionality constant to be determined. My approach at this problem has been to try and exploit the CCR between position and momentum operators, since $[p_z,\mathcal{H}]\neq 0$ ($V$ is explicitly dependent on $z$) and similarly $[z,\mathcal{H}]\neq 0$. We have that $\langle e_n|[p_z,z]|e_n\rangle=\langle e_n|p_zz-zp_z|e_n\rangle=i\hbar$. Using the resolution of the identity with arbitrary $|e_m\rangle$ states, $\sum_m\langle e_n|p_z|e_m\rangle\langle e_m|z|e_n\rangle=i\hbar+\sum_m\langle e_n|z|e_m\rangle\langle e_m|p_z|e_n\rangle$. This is about where I get stuck. While I would like to use $p_z=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dz}$ and orthogonality to make the second term on the right vanish, this reasoning would be inconsistent, since nothing makes the momentum matrix element on the left side special. Otherwise, I don't quite know what to do, since the $|e_i\rangle$'s are not eigenstates of position or momentum here. Is there a better way to go about this problem?

Use the commutation relation $[z,\mathcal{H}]=[z,p_z^2]/2m=i\hbar p_z/m$ sandwiched between the energy eigenstates $|e_n\rangle$ and $|e_m\rangle$, where $\mathcal{H} |e_m\rangle =E_m |e_m\rangle$.
